# How do you use Django Login function properly

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

What I understand so far is that when you're using regular Django you import and use `AuthenticationForm` and you put the `request.POST` there and it will retrieve the user you're looking for. But in this case I'm using DRF and some third party authentication system that retrieve the user for me. so in order to test the login function I made this dummy code to test it:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def login_view(request):

    if request.method == "GET":

        #actuall users that exist
        user =     {  
        "id": 1,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "name": "melly",
        "date_joined": "2021-07-09T11:33:44.440889Z"
        }

        login(request, user)


    return Response('test')
```

and it gave me this error
[image]

Can someone explain to me about this error and why is this happening, thank you!

Comment: It is because `login` requires a user object, not just any dict that looks like a user. If you are using DRF, then the user would be in `request.user` (given that you authenticated properly). At this point, you are already logged in so no need to call `login` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in), the `login` function takes an HttpRequest object and a User object (not a dict), so you dummy code should be probably be something like that :

`user, has_been_created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=test@gmail.com, ...)`.

But please note that the REST API are supposed to be stateless, so you should probably avoid to use the `login` (based on Django's sessions) and returns a token to your user instead.

This is called token authentication and you can find docs for DRF [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).